# How do I unit test calling a service with promise-retry using Mocha?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, promise, mocha.js

I have an action in my ReactJS project that calls a notification service. It is required that, if the service call fails once, I must try calling the service again only one time before proceeding with the error state in the application. I used the promise-retry module for this and was able to get it working locally. However, I am now trying to write unit tests (Mocha) for the promiseRetry-wrapped service calls themselves and having incredible difficulty getting meaningful tests to pass. First, here is the action that calls the service, wrapped in a promiseRetry.

```
import promiseRetry from 'promise-retry';

...

const sendNotification = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const request = buildNotificationRequest(getState);

        dispatch(createNotificationAttempt());

        promiseRetry((retry) => {
            return createNotificationService(request)
                .catch(retry);
            }, {retries: 1}).then(
                () => {
                    dispatch(createNotificationSuccess());
                },
                (error) => {
                    dispatch(createNotificationError(error));
                }
            );
        };
    };
```

Typically, the way that I would write unit tests for actions calling services is something like this:

```
describe('notification actions', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        sendNotification = sinon.stub(services, 'createNotificationService').returns(Promise.resolve({}));
    });

    it('should log an attempt', () => {
        store.dispatch(notificationActions.sendNotification());
        const actions = store.getActions();
        expect(actions[0].type).to.equal(notificationActions.ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_NOTIFICATION_ATTEMPT);
    });
});
```

This works fine for testing the initial attempt, but for some reason, even though I can debug and step through the tests and hit all of the code inside the promiseRetry, the actions inside of them (such as dispatch(createNotificationSuccess())) are not logged in the store, so I cannot run expect statements on them. Every angle I have tried up to this point only retrieves the attempt from the store, and I cannot get any data from the success or failure side of the Promise.

I have found some information on Stack Overflow about testing promise-retry itself, but I need to know that if I stub the service I'm calling and force it to fail, that it will log another attempt and another failure. Or, if I stub the service and force it to succeed, it will only log one attempt, one success, and complete. As I mentioned previously, the only action I am getting in the store is the attempt, and nothing about success or failure, even though stepping through debug shows that all of those lines of code are hit.

Here is an example of a test that I cannot get to pass:

```
import * as services from 'services.js';

...

describe('the first time the service call fails', () => {
    const error = {status: 404};

    beforeEach(() => {
        sendNotification = sinon.stub(services, 'createNotificationService').returns(Promise.reject(error));
    });

    it('should log a retry', () => {
        store.dispatch(notificationActions.sendNotification());
        const actions = store.getActions();
        expect(actions[0].type).to.equal(notificationActions.ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_NOTIFICATION_ATTEMPT); // this passes
        expect(actions[1].type).to.equal(notificationActions.ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_NOTIFICATION_FAILURE); // this fails because there are no other actions logged in the store.
```

Maybe I am misunderstanding the way promise-retry works? Shouldn't it hit my error action (dispatch(createNotificationError(error)) the first time it fails, and the second time (if applicable)? If not, it should be at least logging two attempts. Any advice?

Comment: The code is incomplete. There's no createNotificationService, it's unclear where it comes from, and what's `services`, and why `sinon.stub(services, 'createNotificationService')` should work.

Comment: I updated the pseudo code. The createNotificationService lives in services.js. It's a simple axios.get() call.

Comment: Tested code is asynchronous while tests are synchronous. The problem is specific to Redux testing because there's no promise to chain in tests. I'm not sure what a good strategy would be here, possibly to mock/spy `promise-retry` module and chain a promise from it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @estus, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: what @estus said, typically for testing promises you stub the promise and force it to return `Promise.resolve('mock data')`